# Relevance of "Crossroads of Twilight" title to the story

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

After reading the "Wheel of Time" series by Robert Jordan, I don't understand why book 10 was named "Crossroads of Twilight." I don't remember there being any sort of crossroads in this book whatsoever. Why is the book named this? Is there something I missed while reading?

Comment: There's a couple of passing (and non-relevant) mentions of crossroads in the book, once in the glossary ("*It is held to be especially dangerous to meet the Wild Hunt at a crossroads*") and once in the text ("*Just before sunrise was one of the worst times to meet the Wild Hunt, when darkness was changing to light but the light had not taken hold. At least there was no crossroads nearby...*"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The crossroad (of the title) is mentioned in the intro to the book:

> "And it shall come to pass, in the days when the Dark Hunt rides, when
>   the right hand falters and the left hand strays, that **mankind shall
>   come to the Crossroads of Twilight and all that is, all that was, and
>   all that will be shall balance on the point of a sword, while the
>   winds of the Shadow grow.**"
>
> *From the Prophecies of the Dragon; translation believed done by Jain
>   Charin, known as Jain Farstrider, shortly before his disappearance.*

The [publisher marketing blurb](http://www.abebooks.com/book-search/title/wheel-of-time/author/robert-jordan/first-edition/pics/sortby/1/n/200000013/) states that:

> "In the tenth book of the Wheel of Time from the New York Times #1
>   bestselling author Robert Jordan, **the world and the characters stand
>   at a crossroads, and the world approaches twilight, when the power of
>   the Shadow grows stronger.**"